# Delete join and left message in telegram for c#

Tags: c#, left-join, telegram, telegram-bot

I want make a Telegram bot with **C#** and I Want this bot delete join and left message in group automatically but I don't know how do It if you can help me .
Thank you
I use Telegram bot API
https://github.com/TelegramBots/telegram.bot

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You should search on google before asking here, Or add your code if you have already :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
class Program
{
    static readonly TelegramBotClient Bot = new TelegramBotClient("API-KEY");

    static void Main()
    {
        Bot.StartReceiving();
        Bot.OnMessage += Bot_OnMessage;
    }

    private static async void Bot_OnMessage(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Message.Type == MessageType.ChatMemberLeft || e.Message.Type == MessageType.ChatMemberAdded)
        {
            await Bot.DeleteMessageAsync(e.Message.Chat, e.Message.MessageId);
        }
    }
}
```